# Load Particle System or Other Format From A VDB File?

Tags: swift, particle-system, visionos

Is it possible to load a particle system into a RealityView from a VDB file?

VDB files are commonly used to store volumetric particle effect systems. The file format was originally created by DreamWorks. Due to Apple's partnership with Disney, it would seem more advanced formats like VDB files should be enabled within the platform.

Is there a way to load one as a particle system or another entity into the Vision Pro, specifically a RealityView?